# What should I reply when someone sends me an extremely boring link?

Tags: social-media, instant-messaging

I regularly get very boring links from my colleague/friend. I do not know how to react to this.

1. Should I reply?
2. What should I say when I do reply?
3. Is it considered rude to just ignore and move on?

Comment: What are the links about? i.e are they work related, are the unfunny jokes, do friends/colleagues think this is something that would interest you?

Comment: If you want to apparently make them question everything, I'd go with ["Thank you"](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3762/i-sent-an-interesting-link-to-a-friend-that-he-didnt-ask-for-at-all-and-he-rep).  (Somewhat related question from the other perspective)

Comment: How is this a duplicate? One question is specifically asking for how to get them to **stop** and this question is asking **what to do**.

Comment: @Catija the OP is asking **what to say**, and then suggests if it is best to ignore the links. The older question is also asking **what to do** about receiving boring links. The two questions are certainly connected.

Comment: Where are you located? Whether something is rude depends on your culture. (2) What goal are you trying to accomplish here? To get your friend to stop sending you the links? This question should be closed until those two issues are addressed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Connected, sure... but we don't dupe **connected** questions, we dupe *Identical* ones. One person **clearly** wants to stop them, the other person is asking how to/whether to respond. Not the same thing.

Comment: @Catija There will never be two *identical* questions, there will always be some (minor) detail that will make each question unique to its author.   The topic is about receiving unsolicited unfunny links and what to do. This also includes "what to say", which both questions ask about.

Comment: That depends on weather they send those links to you specifically or just mass spam their contact list with some "interesting" stuff they came across. 

If it's a mass text then it's pretty safe to ignore.

If it is sent to you specifically, then you should probably reply with something, ignoring it will not lead them to realization that you don't care for the links, it'll just make you seem forgetful and/or uncaring. Unless they send multiple links every day, with no text just the link. If all they did was click a "share" button on some article that doesn't warrant a reply

Answer (score 1):

The person sending this is probably not expecting you find it boring and is most likely just doing it as a nice gesture of small talk.

It would be rude not to reply at all, if your friend is over at your house and starts talking about a subject you don't like, you don't simply ignore them or walk away either, do you?

If you want to show them you have no interest in this, reply with something like:

> Thanks for the link! 'X' is not really my thing though.

Or if you want to return the small talk gesture:

> Thanks for the link; however, I'm not really interested in X. I enjoy Y more, what do you think of Y?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replying would be the nice thing to do. But as long as it is just a link, without any text with it I think ignoring it might be fine as well.
2. Reply with the -_- smilie. Works every time!
3. Probably not, unless it's like "hey, look at this link: ..., what do you think of it"?